# Bash not able to change file content

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a strange issue.

There is file on which:

```
$ cat fp_id_led
1
$ echo 0 > fp_id_led
$ cat fp_id_led
1 <--- Still shows 1!
```

Also when I open the file in vim its just empty.
How can I flip that value in the file.

Answer (score 4):

Probably the file is located not on a normal filesystem, but on a pseudo filesystem, like `/proc`?

Comment: Yes it is indeed. Asking as a noob, can I not change the value then?

Comment: +1 for mentioning non-normal file systems :)

Comment: It depends on file. Of that file obviously not :)

Comment: what if you do the same in /tmp? I am sure you are touching a virtual file. Nothing wrong with your command in bash.